# javascript get time zone

Tags: javascript, timezone, clock

Hello i have this code in Javascript but i want to change the time zone GMT1 GMT2 and i can't fount where i must do the changes maybe can help me someone?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    setInterval( function() {
        var seconds = new Date().getSeconds();
        var sdegree = seconds * 6;
        var srotate = "rotate(" + sdegree + "deg)";

        $("#sec_rus").css({"-moz-transform" : srotate, "-webkit-transform" : srotate});

    }, 1000 );


    setInterval( function() {
        var hours = new Date().getHours();
        var mins = new Date().getMinutes();
        var hdegree = hours * 30 + (mins / 2);
        var hrotate = "rotate(" + hdegree + "deg)";

        $("#hour_rus").css({"-moz-transform" : hrotate, "-webkit-transform" : hrotate});

    }, 1000 );


    setInterval( function() {
        var mins = new Date().getMinutes();
        var mdegree = mins * 6;
        var mrotate = "rotate(" + mdegree + "deg)";

        $("#min_rus").css({"-moz-transform" : mrotate, "-webkit-transform" : mrotate});

    }, 1000 );

}); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `var hours = new Date.getUTCHours() + 2;`